# Generate Non-Singular Matrix of $n\times n$ dimension

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to create a function that will make an $n\times n$ matrix which is non-singular that will always retrieve the same matrix (meaning that the matrix will not be random each time).

I tried using the table function with different expressions using $i$ and $j$ but they always ended up singular because they had similar rules.

So please don't give me a random matrix, the matrix needs to have a pattern that if two people used the function on different computers with the same $n$ value, they would get the same matrix

P.S. Keep the matrix in the Real set of numbers (also Integers) and don't make them too high so that its not too big to work with (I want the values to be ideally under 20)

Comment: I couldn't resist: `IdentityMatrix[n]`

Comment: hmm yeah thats not gonna work, I'm doing Matrix Cryptography and I am going to pretend that the person I send the encrypted matrix knows the encoding matrix and using the Identity Matrix to encode it, won't be that encrypted.

Comment: I know it is not what are you looking for but it fits the question :) that's I couldn't resist to post it :)

Comment: true true, well thanks, I'll update it in the OP, but the matrix should be only Integers, so Nassers answer won't work

Comment: I am confused. You say `but the matrix should be only Integers, so Nassers answer won't work` but `HankelMatrix`  is all integers. May be you meant  should NOT be integers?

Comment: in your answer you had 4.09288, 5.13808 and so forth, they don't look like integers, unless they aren't the answer and I'm just not reading it right

Comment: I have posted my answer that I am going to use below, however it does not work for all values of $n$, but is functional for the values of $n$ I need

Answer (score 5):

A non-singular matrix is a matrix with full rank. You can use any orthogonal basis, for example:

```
Table[HermiteH[i, j], {i, 5}, {j, 5}]
```

For a 5x5 non-singular matrix. There are several more basis generating function in *Mathematica*.

Since these numbers can be a bit big, here's a way of generating non-singular, non-random matrices with entries between -1 and 1:

```
orthMatrix[n_] := Orthogonalize[RandomReal[1, {n, n}]]
```

To make it non-random we use `SeedRandom`:

```
SeedRandom[1337]; orthMatrix[10]
```

Comment: wow, that has HUGH condition number! `MatrixConditionNumber[
  Table[HermiteH[i, j], {i, 5}, {j, 5}]] // N` gives 431620. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number that will cause about 5 decimal point accuracy loss?

Comment: @Nasser We don't really know what the requirements for the matrix is. I'm just pointing out that `HermiteH`, `LaguerreL`, `BesselJ` etc. all solves the problem in a straightforward manner.

Comment: Sure. But high condition number will cause numerical problems when used for Ax=b problems. But there are many ways to generate random matrices that are not singular. just googled it. So, fixing the seed to fixed value before starting the random number generator will cause the same matrix to be generated each time.

Comment: @Nasser Added such a method.

Comment: Using your last method with the orthMatrix, my values are all decimals, is there a way to make them integers under a maximum value?

Comment: @user9053 By default, `Orthogonalize` uses the Gram-Schmidt process which will not maintain integer values. I don't know how to orthogonalize like that, so I'm afraid not. You can move the matrix into any interval (say between 0 and 20) by sufficient addition and multiplication by constants.

Comment: Thanks, that solution sounds like one I will use, I mean theoretically, in my situation, $n$ is only going to be between 5 and around 15, so this is a good option

Comment: @user9053 srry, deleted the comment because I realized it was only true for certain n. *facepalm*

Answer (score 4):

maybe Hankel?

```
N[LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber[HankelMatrix[#]]] & /@ Range[4, 32]

{4.09288, 5.13808, 6.11956, 7.14252, 8.1322, 9.14612, 10.1395, \
11.1489, 12.1443, 13.151, 14.1477, 15.1527, 16.1502, 17.1541, \
18.1521, 19.1552, 20.1536, 21.1562, 22.1548, 23.157, 24.1559, \
25.1577, 26.1567, 27.1583, 28.1574, 29.1588, 30.1581, 31.1593, \
32.1586}
```

Comment: I updated it in the OP, but I forgot to mention that all values are integers :/ thanks anyways

Comment: but it IS all integers. That what Hankel matrix is. The above is NOT the matrix, these are the conditions numbers. Showing the matrix is stable numerically.

Comment: oh, ok, I tested it out in Mathematica and it seems like the best for my scenario so far, I will keep this option open

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
n = 5;
Partition[Prime /@ Range[n^2], n]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 5, 7, 11},
>  {13, 17, 19, 23, 29}, 
>  {31, 37, 41, 43, 47}, 
>  {53, 59, 61, 67, 71}, 
>  {73, 79, 83, 89, 97}}
> ```

a little improvement:

```
Prime@Array[Plus, {n, n}]
```

> ```
> {{3, 5, 7, 11, 13}, 
>  {5, 7, 11, 13, 17}, 
>  {7, 11, 13, 17, 19}, 
>  {11, 13, 17, 19, 23}, 
>  {13, 17, 19, 23, 29}}
> ```

it will generate lower values because rows will overlap in n-1 posistions. Also I used the fact that `Prime` is listable.

Comment: Thanks, this is my favourite, and this will work for all values of n?

Comment: @user9053 it suppose to but for huge `n` it may be slow and generate huge values :) I don't have big experience with primes so you have to check if it is good for your purposes :) Please, do not accept so fast, the question is quite new, let's do not discourage others :) you can still upvote if you like it

Comment: High condition number also !

Comment: I'll unaccept the answer for the moment, and if it's the best answer later I'll accept it

Comment: @user9053 Ok ;). Also, take a look at my edit, it will generate lower values.

Comment: That looks a lot nicer, it gets better everytime. Can you explain how the added bit works? I am unsure how it works (only the Prime@ and Plus) bits

Comment: @user9053 Array[Plus,{n,n}] is generatig n$x$n matrix with entries Plus[i,j] where i,j are row/column indices. Prime is taking n-th Prime for each n=Plus[i,j]. Try single `Array[Plus, {n, n}]` and look what it is generating and then add `Prime@`, we don't have to `Map` the `Prime` because of its `Listable` attribute. More in documenteation center.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I decided on a method similar to Anon's solution

I am just going to use

```
SeedRandom[value];EncodingMatrix=RandomInteger[1,{dimension,dimension}]
```

However I wanted to find an optimal seed for my scenario. I generally wanted to have all values of $n$ from 1 - 20 so I made the following program to find it out

```
GetEncodingMatrix[Dimensions_,Seed_]:=(SeedRandom[Seed];RandomInteger[1,{Dimension,Dimension}])
TestValid[n_]:=(state="True";For[i=1,i<21,i++,If[Det[GetEncodingMatrix[i,n]]==0,state="False"]];state)
n=1;While[n<5000,If[TestValid[n]=="true",Print[n]];n++]
```

> 1918, 3381, 3385

$\therefore$ My seed value should work for those values.

If anyone refers back to this and needs to make it work for every value of $n$, I recommend any of the other three options as they are all excellent